# Nested If Statements in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script

My apologies if my issue has already been asked in other posts, but I wasn't able to find any. I am writing a little shell script which requires me to write a nested if statement. I am not really sure I am doing it right. I get no errors, but the program isn't functioning as I expect it. What I want is: If the file is already in `MasterFile.txt`, then the user has the option to either take another set of data by saying `y` or `Y`, or say `n` or `N` to terminate the program. *Problem: Script does not terminate*. If the file does not exist in `MasterFile.txt`, then take the data set. Here's the code:

```
if grep -q "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}" MasterFile.txt;
then {
   echo "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2} already exists in the MasterFile. Would you like to proceed?"
   read string3
   if "${string3}" = 'Y' || "${string3}" = 'y'; then {
      screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
      screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
      sleep 8s
      screen -S trans -X quit
   }
   else{return}
   fi
else{
#opening screen & begin analysis
screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
sleep 8s
screen -S trans -X quit
}
fi
```

Comment: Um... what shell is this? `sh`-type shells don't use `{ ... }` for blocks.

Comment: I believe its bash. The program worked just fine with just one if statement. I don't think `{...}` is the problem. There must be something wrong with the way I implemented the nested `if`

Comment: Now I get an error that says there is something wrong with the last `else` statement

Comment: @Kusalananda, well, you could use them for command grouping there as well as elsewhere ...

Comment: @Ptheguy `if "${string3}" = 'Y'` takes the contents of `string3` as the name of a command, and runs it with two arguments `=` and `Y`...

Comment: @Kusalananda `{...}` works fine for a block in POSIX shells, though they aren't necessary/standard here (and probably at least one of them won't work because it lacks a closing `;`)

Comment: @EricRenouf, [a newline should be fine](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) there before the closing `}`. (oh, but the `else{return}` is missing it.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Right, but `{return}` has neither

Comment: @Eric, yep, I missed that one at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick rewrite with more conventional syntax:

```
if grep -q "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}" MasterFile.txt; then 
   echo "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2} already exists in the MasterFile. Would you like to proceed?"
   read string3
   if [[ "${string3^}" == 'Y' ]]; then
      screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
      screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
      sleep 8s
      screen -S trans -X quit
   else
       exit 0
   fi
else
    #opening screen & begin analysis
    screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
    screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
    sleep 8s
    screen -S trans -X quit
fi
```

You don't appear to have any functions declared here, so `return` is not valid for this use-case.  I have presumed that a non-affirmative answer to your prompted question is meant to abort the entire script, hence the use of `exit`.

The construct `${variable^}` will force the first character of `$variable`, if a letter, to be upper-case, which simplifies the response check.

Comment: So two things: one if I enter `y` it quits, and regardless of what I enter, i get the following error `./test/sh: line19: [[variable: command not found`

Comment: ensure that the first line of the script is `#!/bin/bash`, and not `#!/bin/sh`.  `[[ [...] ]]` constructs are a `bash`ism.

Comment: yes, the header is correct

Comment: And you have a space between `[[` and `"${string3^}"`?

Comment: That was it!! Thank you once more. If you have the time, do you mind teaching me what `[[` means and why a space can be so important?

Comment: The case modification operator was introduced in [Bash version-4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html).  Verify you are running it with `bash --version`

Comment: The `[[ [...] ]]` syntax is a more reliable and robust version of the older, `[ [...] ]` or `test` syntax.  The spaces are simply syntactically required.  These constructs are used for simple tests and comparisons; see `man test` for details.